# Как можно соединить 2 обьекта с вложенностью

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 обьекта:

```
Ojb1: {
   map: ['item 1', 'item 2'],
   settings: {
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2
   }
}

Ojb2: {
   map: ['item 3'],
   settings: {
      key3: 3
   }
}
```

как можно добавить всё что есть в obj2 в obj1 чтобы получилось:

```
Ojb1: {
       map: ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'],
       settings: {
          key1: 1,
          key2: 2,
          key3: 3
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Встроенного ничего нет. Вам нужно самому рекурсивно пройтись по всем полям и пообъединять их

```js
const obj1 = {
   map: ['item 1', 'item 2'],
   settings: {
      key1: 1,
      key2: 2
   },
   d: 5
};

const obj2 = {
   map: ['item 3'],
   settings: {
      key3: 3
   },
   d: 6
};

function merge(target, ...sources) {
  for (let srcIdx = 0; srcIdx < sources.length; srcIdx++) {
    const source = sources[srcIdx];
    for (let fldIdx in source) {
      const srcFld = source[fldIdx];
      if (typeof target[fldIdx] === "object") {
        if (Array.isArray(target[fldIdx]))
          target[fldIdx] = target[fldIdx].concat(srcFld);
        else
          merge(target[fldIdx], srcFld);
      } else {
        if (typeof srcFld === "object") {
          if (Array.isArray(srcFld))
            target[fldIdx] = [].concat(srcFld);
          else
            target[fldIdx] = merge({}, srcFld);
        } else
          target[fldIdx] = srcFld;
      }
    }
  }
  return target;
}

const obj3 = merge({}, obj1, obj2);

console.log(3, obj3);
console.log(1, obj1);
console.log(2, obj2);
```